# android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator isn't working

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm using a ListView with the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1 style used on an ArrayAdapter for the TextView elements, similar to the List16.java example.

I'd like my ListView to have multi-selection, so I implemented MultiChoiceModeListener and set the CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL. Long-pressing on an item correctly opens the CAB, however I have an issue with item selection - items in the lists don't visually change as they are selected/deselected in this mode.

As far as I understand, `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` is responsible for the background colour on the state change - and so this does not seem to be working.

I'm using ABS 4.2.0 in my app as well. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you already found a solution?

I had the same problem... But I solved it!

I did 2 things:

1. I added `android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"` to my Custom Row layout. I don't know about the `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1` style, but I guess it should work too...
2. In my `OnItemLongClickListener` I added `listView.setItemChecked(position, true);`
   This, however, added a new problem: the item wouldn't get deselected when closing the ActionBar, so in `onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)`, I added: 
   `listView.clearChoices();`
   `listView.requestLayout();`

Greetings,

Sven

Comment: Afraid I can't use setItemChecked with CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL per documentation :(